# ending my game with a while loop -- java

Tags: java, arraylist, while-loop

I added this code as I was trying to make a TicTacToe Game. Initially the game only played for a single turn, but I needed a way to make it end after the players played the game to finish. But when i ran the code, it didn't even make a turn play. I tested it earlier with a simple while(a>3){/*play turn*/ a++;} and it worked for the most part, but the loop failed to properly end, just leaving it tapering and forcing me to manually shut down my terminal.

http://hastebin.com/iziselusex.tex

This is my turns method since you asked for it

http://hastebin.com/isoxifufeq.axapta

And this contains the Initialize method, as well as the methods mentioned in the turns function

```
    int[][] anArray = new int[3][3];
    aBoard.initialize();

    int end = 0;

    int t = 0;

    while(end != 1){ //so long as end isn't reached, the game will still play
        while(t < 4){ //there are a total of 4 turns that can take place before the board is filled up. 5 if you include the last piece, but i wasn't sure about including it.
            anArray = this.turns(anArray);//this starts the turn

            if((anArray[0][0] == anArray[1][1]) && (anArray[1][1] == anArray[2][2])){
                end = 1;
            }else if((anArray[0][2] == anArray[1][1]) && (anArray[1][1] == anArray[2][0])){
                end = 1;
            }else if((anArray[0][0] == anArray[0][1]) && (anArray[0][1] == anArray[0][2])){
                end = 1;
            }else if((anArray[1][0] == anArray[1][1]) && (anArray[1][1] == anArray[1][2])){
                end = 1;
            }else if((anArray[2][0] == anArray[2][1]) && (anArray[2][1] == anArray[2][2])){
                end = 1;
            }else if((anArray[0][0] == anArray[1][0]) && (anArray[1][0] == anArray[2][0])){
                end = 1;
            }else if((anArray[0][1] == anArray[1][1]) && (anArray[1][1] == anArray[2][1])){
                end = 1;
            }else if((anArray[0][2] == anArray[1][2]) && (anArray[1][2] == anArray[2][2])){
                end = 1;
            }else{
                end = 0;
            }//this checks for possible victories that could have been made during the last turn

            t++; //starts the next cycle over again
        }
        end = 1; //once all the turns are exhausted, the game ends

        if(end == 1){
           aView.println("The game is finished!");
           System.exit(0);
        }
    }
```

edit: I added an exit function at the end and fixed the second while loop issue (no more t > 4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first of all, the second while needs to be while (t < 4) since t starts at 0, t > 4 will evaluate to false right away and not even run the loop body.

Comment: now i feel like an idiot for missing that, but after i tested it, i got the exact same problem where the code just tapers and refuses to end. I even tried to add a System.exit(0) [which i'll add in the example] and it didn't change it

Comment: Could you please paste the turns and initialize functions?  What do you mean it "tapers"?

Comment: If I posted the turns and initialize functions i'd end up having to give at least 50 lines of code. Not something i think is right. Perhaps i should hastebin it?

and by tapers, i mean, this: I use my mac's Terminal to run my code. typically, when the code ends, it returns to the basic line ~Java [insert name here]. but instead, it just leaves me on the screen, with the code still "active" but nothing is happening. I type, i click enter, but nothing is done

Comment: 50 more lines is not too long.  Looks like it's stuck in a loop somewhere but I suspect it's in the turns function.

Comment: i added some hastebins, just in case considering the turns method includes reference to code in several methods in another class

Answer (score 0):

As @Andrew pointed out, your second loop condition `while(t > 4)` will never evaluate to true because it enters your first loop with the value of 0. Change this to `while(t < 4)` and you will at least be entering your "game loop".

You also should be setting the value of `t = 0` after your first loop but before your second loop like so:

```
while(end != 1) { //so long as end isn't reached, the game will still play
    t = 0; // reset the value of 't' so we will enter inner loop again
    while(t < 4) {
    ...
```

Comment: first, thanks for the input.

second, i included the while(end != 1) because i needed to change "end" to 1 when the timer ran out, but keep it from permanently changing the value of "end". since a permanent "end" would just lead to the game ending prematurely

Comment: Actually that's my mistake, the outer loop isn't completely pointless - if you reach your end = 0 condition on the last run of the inner loop. But another error does pop up in that situation because then you're stuck in the outer loop because the value of t is never reset to 0.

Comment: my expectation was to shut down the code once the game finished, so you'd have to restart the entire code anyway just to play it again. so t's value would be reset also